# gstreamer green screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: streaming, buffer, pipeline, gstreamer, ubuntu-20.04

i tried to use this pipeline to create a video streaming for some .png pictures.

SENDER:
auto rtsp_pipeline = "appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width= 1920, height= 1080,framerate=10/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=80000 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port= 5010";

output_stream = cv::VideoWriter(rtsp_pipeline, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, frame_rate, cv::Size(1920, 1080), true);

timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(100ms, std::bind(&PipelineSimulator::timer_callback, this));

with this timer_callback:
img_ = cv::imread(this->filenames[current_index]);
output_stream.write(img_);

RECEIVER:
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5010 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

this is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY5bc.png)

I don't know where the problem is.

I tried to change the color format. But i think it is a problem buffer

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver may be waiting for an intra frame that it hasn't yet received. You may add property `key-int-max` of x264enc for the affordable setup time, such as 30 frames for 3s @10fps:

```
pipeline = "appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width= 1920, height= 1080,framerate=10/1 ! queue ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=80000 speed-preset=superfast insert-vui=1 key-int-max=30 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5010";
```

On receiver side, you may also add rtpjitterbuffer and adjust its latency property for your case:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5010 ! queue ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=0
```